# Check in/out cards

Tags: react.js, jsx

putting the if-else block outside of a function looks clutter to me, should I just put it inside a function and then inside the useEffect ?

**Purpose of the if-else block**: Render the cards base on the value pass from index.js

Below is my displayItem code

displayItem.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Card } from "antd";
import { data } from "./data.js";

export default function DisplayItem(props) {
  let [minValue, setMinValue] = useState(0);
  let [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState(0);

  let [columnStyle, setColumn] = useState({});
  let [update, setUpdate] = useState(true);

  if (props.value === 6 && update) {
    setColumn({ float: "left", width: "30%", padding: "5px" });
    setMaxValue(props.value);
    setUpdate(false);
  } else if (props.value === 4 && update) {
    setColumn({ float: "left", width: "40%", padding: "5px" });
    setMaxValue(props.value);
    setUpdate(false);
  }

  const createCards = (i, item) => {
    console.log("maxValue ", props.value);
    return (
      <div key={i} style={columnStyle}>
        <Card className="custom-card" bodyStyle={{ padding: 0 }}>
          <div
            className="custom-card-content"
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "green",
              color: "white"
            }}
          >
            <label> Name: {item.name} </label> <br />
            <label> Check IN: {item.checkin} </label> <br />
            <label> Check Out: {item.checkout} </label>
          </div>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {data.slice(minValue, maxValue).map((item, i) => {
          return i >= minValue && i <= maxValue && createCards(i, item);
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-http-84bh1?file=/src/displayItems.js)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/269444/5) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't repeat yourself](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
if (update && (props.value === 6 || props.value === 4) {
    setColumn({ float: "left", width: 
        (props.value === 6 ? "30%" : "40%"), padding: "5px" });
    setMaxValue(props.value);
    setUpdate(false);
}
```